# how to switch widgets in a QSplitter

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

How to modify a `QSplitter` panels from right to left, or center, without deleting the splitter and recreate it.

I uses `replaceWidget`, but it is giving: `QSplitter::replaceWidget: Trying to replace a widget with one of its siblings`, and `QSplitter::replaceWidget: Trying to replace a widget with itself`

```
    widget_1, widget_2, widget_3, widget_4 = QWidget(), QWidget(), QWidget(), QWidget() 
    splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    splitter1.addWidget(widget_1)
    splitter1.addWidget(widget_2)
    splitter1.setSizes([450, 350])
    splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    splitter2.addWidget(widget_3)
    splitter2.addWidget(widget_4)
    splitter2.setSizes([550, 250])        
    splitter3 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter3.setObjectName('align_left')
    splitter3.addWidget(splitter1)
    splitter3.addWidget(splitter2)
    splitter3.setSizes([100, 1000])

    right_panel, left_panel = splitter3.widget(0), splitter3.widget(1) 
    splitter3.replaceWidget(0, left_panel)
    splitter3.replaceWidget(1, right_panel)
```

I further tried to create two `QSplitter` using the same instances, but seems i need to create different instances for each `QSplitter`

I tried also, but not working

```
   for i in reversed(range(splitter3.count())):
        panel = splitter3.widget(i)
        panel.setParent(None)                   
    
    if align_panel == 'left':
        splitter3.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter3.addWidget(splitter2)
        splitter3.setSizes([100, 1000])
    elif align_panel == 'right':
        splitter3.addWidget(splitter2)
        splitter3.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter3.setSizes([1000, 100])
```

Comment: The documentation clearly says that `replaceWidget` doesn't work if the widget is already a child of the splitter, which means that you have to make it *not* its child. Use `setParent(None)` on the widget you want to move, but remember that if that widget is *before* the position you are going to move it, the new index will have to be subtracted by one (since you removed an item).

Comment: Yes, I think I missed that subtract by one